# Boot spring hibernate+jpa not returning database level generated column

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity in my spring boot application, which is backed by an SQL Server database.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=TABLE)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(
        columnDefinition="datetime default current_timestamp",
        nullable=false, updatable=false, insertable = false
    )
    private String strTimestamp;
    // ...
}
```

Calling save using JpaRepository works and the id is generated but the strTimestamp is null even if I immediately call `getOne` or call (native query) `select * from people where id = ?`, with the newly returned Id, the column still comes out null.

The interesting thing is that if I hard code an id of a previously inserted row, it returns that record.

I'd like to return the whole row after insertion because I need the generated column(s).

How may I be able to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change strTimestamp data type to `java.util.Date` and try. use `@Temporal` annotation also

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column( columnDefinition="datetime default current_timestamp", nullable=false, updatable=false, insertable = false ) private String strTimestamp;
```